# Question about software licensing

Tags: licensing

I don't know if this is the appropriate exchange site for this question, but here it goes:

http://ckfinder.com/ has 3 licenses.

I would like to incorporate this software into my existing CMS, but am a little confused as to whether I need the OEM license, or the Corporate license: http://ckfinder.com/purchase

I typically use this CMS for third party clients who request a content management system for a their pre-existing sites. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: It sounds like OEM (or multiple "web site" licenses), since the clients own their sites that are just using your CMS to run them. Not your logo in the corner means not your site. But you're asking for legal advice or at least a question that would be better directed toward their license support.

Comment: Yeah, why don't you just ask **them**?

Answer (score 2):

I'd ask them - they state this on the website:

*"CKFinder licensing offering is extremely flexible, fitting all usage needs and situations. In case of special requirements or doubts, please be sure to contact us."*